# Is there a way to press "`" this key in auto hot key script?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

**I am trying to press,**

```
` << this symbol key on keyboard
```

this key in keyboard which is below `ESC` key.
But can't able to achieve it.

**Code I tried 1,**

```
Send, `
return
```

**Code I tried 2,**

```
Send, {`}
return
```

**Code I tried 3,**

```
Send {`}
return
```

Nothing works, as I tried from its documentation.
How to press that key then ? (not as hotkey) as typing or pressing when any hotkey triggered

**For example, when I press ALT + C it have to send or type or press ` this.**

```
!c:: #for alt+c
Send, {`} #is not working
```

**Every other key works fine,**

```
!c::
Send, {Enter} #works fine
Send, {Up} #works fine
Send, {`} #not working
```

**may be any other name for that key !**

Comment: Can you please describe better? Unterstand I right that you want a script which output is `\`` for input `Alt+c`?

Comment: Yes exactly, Need a script to keypress or type ` this key in auto hot key (ahk) script for any input (as i said alt+c for example) and am ok with any key combo

Comment: @PhilipRamya Your code examples 2 and 3 are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question the solution should be

```
{input}::SendRaw ``
```

Comment: `{input}` is !c:: fine with that, but after that Send "`" is not working thats the issue, it types only double quotes not ` this

Comment: Do you use v1 or v2 of ahk?

Comment: I am using `Version 1.1.36.02` seen from ahk help.

Comment: corrected my answer for ahk v1

Comment: It shows error, SendRaw requires at least 1 parameter and yes I have typed correctly. kindly help

Comment: A better solution I cannot provide sorry.

Comment: Your new updated answer types ` but, also includes this char "Â " donno where that come from, but, one good news brother, I found the solution with your previous code which is SendRaw ` , instead using one symbol using twice the same symbol make type it once. thats what exactly needed and succeed with your idea only using SendRaw , just using twice that symbol. Thanks a lottttttt. <3

Comment: Solution: SendRaw ``

Comment: Updated my solution :) You can accept if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text):

```
!c::Send {Text}``
```

**The backtick symbol `** has special meaning in AHK as [EscapeChar](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm) and needs to be escaped in order to be interpreted litterally.

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
!c::Send % Chr(96)
```

That will bypass the escape sequence for AHK